# ¿Como consultar datos en MySQL y poder guardar en SQL Server? (Python)

Tags: mysql, python, sql-server, python-3.x

Buen dia tengo una duda, tengo un código generado en Python el cual lo que hace es consultar una tabla de MySQL de nombre `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *, IF(time >= 10,"Bad","Good") AS Estado FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id <> connection_id();
```

Una vez que este cumple mis condiciones por medio de codigo python le mando a decir que guarde esos procesos y ademas los mate con el comando `KILL`, pero los datos que mando a guardar los hago en una tabla que cree en MySQL.

Ahora lo que quiero es seguir consultando en MySQl, pero quiero saber si hay manera de poder guardar los datos consultados en una tabla pero de SQL Server, basicamente consultar en MySQL y guardar en SQL Server.

Anexo el codigo:

```
#! / usr / bin / python
# - * - coding: UTF-8 - * -
import os, sys
import signal, os, sys
import MySQLdb
conexion_mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host = '10.248.204.43', user = 'root', passwd = 'sahc', db = 'Biblioteca')

cur = conexion_mysql.cursor()
consulta = ('SELECT *, IF(time >= 10,"Bad","Good") AS Estado FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id <> connection_id()')
cur.execute(consulta)
for row in cur.fetchall():
    resultado = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]
    sql = "INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (" + str(row[0]) + "," + "'" + (row[1] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[2] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[3] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[4] or '') + "'" + "," + str(row[5]) + "," + "'" + (row[6] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[7] or '') + "'" + "," + "now()" + ")"
    cur.execute(sql)
    conexion_mysql.commit()
    print "Datos Guardados Exitosamente"
    if row[0] == row[0]:
        matar = "KILL " + str(row[0])
        cur.execute(matar)
        conexion_mysql.commit()
        print "Datos eliminados"
```

Como ven consulto y guardo en MySQL, quiero seguir consultando en MySQL pero guardar los datos en SQL Server.

Les agradeceria la ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El consejo de @Patricio Morocho me sirvio pero use otro import quedando el código final asi:

```
#! / usr / bin / python
# - * - coding: UTF-8 - * -
import os, sys
import signal, os, sys
import MySQLdb #MySQL
import pymssql #SQL server 2016

#Conexión a MySQL
conexion_mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host = '10.248.204.43', user = 'root', passwd = 'sahc', db = 'Biblioteca')

#Conexión a SQL Server
server = "AXPOS10"
user = "santiago"
password = "Python@Monitor"
base = "StoragePython"
conexion_sql = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, base)

cur = conexion_mysql.cursor() #Cursor de Mysql
cur2 = conexion_sql.cursor() #Cursor de SQL Server

#Consulta a MySQL
consulta = ('SELECT *, IF(time >= 10,"Bad","Good") AS Estado FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id <> connection_id()')
cur.execute(consulta) #Ejecución de consulta MySQL apartir del for es ejecución a SQL Server y en el if se ejecuta el comando KILL en MySQL
for row in cur.fetchall():
    resultado = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]
    sql = "INSERT INTO LogKillProcesstMySQL VALUES (" + str(row[0]) + "," + "'" + (row[1] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[2] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[3] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[4] or '') + "'" + "," + str(row[5]) + "," + "'" + (row[6] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[7] or '') + "'" + "," + "GETDATE()" + ")"
    cur2.execute(sql) #Ejecución de insertado SQL Server
    conexion_sql.commit()
    print "Datos Guardados Exitosamente"
    if row[0] == row[0]:
        matar = "KILL " + str(row[0])
        cur.execute(matar)
        conexion_mysql.commit()
        print "Datos eliminados"
```

El resultado fue exitoso !

Answer (score 1):

No veo grandes inconvenientes, lo que tienes que hacer es construir una segunda conexión al SQL Server, obviamente vas a tener que utilizar otro package para conectarte a él, yo suelo usar [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pypyodbc/), pero hay varios más. Te adjunto un ejemplo sencillo:

```
import pypyodbc

# Completar <<server>> <<user>> y <<passw>>
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<<server>>;DATABASE=master;UID=<<user>>;PWD=<<passw>>")
cur = conn.cursor()

# Este es tu INSERT revisar compatibilidad MySql / MSSQL
sql = "INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (" + str(row[0]) + "," + "'" + (row[1] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[2] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[3] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[4] or '') + "'" + "," + str(row[5]) + "," + "'" + (row[6] or '') + "'" + "," + "'" + (row[7] or '') + "'" + "," + "now()" + ")"
cur.execute(sql)
cur.commit()

# Cierro conexión
conn.close()
```

Comment: Ok ahora lo pruebo :)

Comment: Hola si me sirvio tu consejo pero use este import: `pymssql`